# Prove this Complicated Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + (a + b + c)^2 \le 4$. Prove that $$\frac{ab + 1}{(a + b)^2} + \frac{bc + 1}{(b + c)^2} + \frac{ca + 1}{(c + a)^2} \ge 3.$$

Let $x = a + b, y = b + c, t = a + c$ Then the INEQ becomes,

$$\frac{ab + 1}{(x)^2} + \frac{bc + 1}{(y)^2} + \frac{ca + 1}{(t)^2} \ge 3.$$

Any further hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = a+b,y= b+c,z = c+a$, then

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 4$$

problem becomes

$$\sum\frac{4 + (x+z-y)(x+y-z)}{4x^2}=\sum \frac{4 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 2yz}{4x^2}$$

$$=\sum\frac{4-x^2 - y^2 -z^2 + 2x^2 + 2yz}{4x^2}\ge \sum\frac{2x^2 + 2yz}{4x^2} $$

$$=\sum \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{yz}{x^2}\right)\ge \frac{3}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3\left(\prod\frac{yz }{x^2}\right)^{1/3} = 3$$

Comment: A few not-so-obvious passage explanations. First, those sums are intended to be over cyclical permutations of $(x,y,z)$, i.e. summing the term with $x,y,z$ as in the sum, then the term where $x$ is renamed to $y$, $y$ to $z$ and $z$ to $x$, then that where $x$ becomes $z$, $y$ becomes $x$ and $z$ turns to $y$. Second, those three terms are precisely those in the inequality, the denominator being obvious save for a four, which is due to the numerator, and the numerator being a purely algebraic manipulation to prove correct, i.e. to be 4 times the original one, with the four below fixing that.

Comment: Third, the first equality in the chain is a purely algebraic expansion of a product. FOurth, the second equality is summing and subtracting $x^2$ and grouping the positive $x^2$s. Fifth, the $\geq$ is because $4-x^2-y^2-z^2\geq0$ due to the equality at the answer's top, which with algebraic calculations can be shown to be equivalent to that given by the question. Sixth, we divide the numerator by the denominator and split the fracion into two summed fractions. Seventh, we see the sum has three $\frac12$, whence the $\frac32$, and the sum of the $\frac{yz}{x^2}$ is greater than their …

Comment: … $\frac32$ their geometric average (cubic root of product) - why? But their product is 1, being $\frac{yz}{x^2}\frac{zx}{y^2}\frac{xy}{z^2}=\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^2y^2z^2}=1$, so we have reched $\frac32+\frac32=3$, as desired. Writing this because I had some trouble figuring it out and thought it might be useful for other readers to have this below the post.

Comment: How do you prove the last $\geq$ holds?

Comment: @MickG AM-GM inequality: $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k>0$ gives $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k\ge k(a_1a_2\cdots a_k)^{1/k}$.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_induction) is a proof of that inequality. I had never seen it before…

Comment: @MickG You must be very new to inequalities. AM-GM inequality is I'd say the most central inequality in proving these olympiad-like inequalities.

Comment: In fact, I have never done GM in school nor in Uni, for what I recall, so it's no wonder I'd never seen that inequality. The most central inequality in what branch of maths? No because I wouldn't see it as central in linear algebra or in abstract algebra...

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+1}{(a+b)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{2ab+2}{(a+b)^2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{2ab+a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+ac+bc}{(a+b)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{c^2+ab+ac+bc}{(a+b)^2}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(c+a)(c+b)}{(a+b)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{(c+a)(c+b)}{(a+b)^2}}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}=3.$$
Done!